# Rank() Over Partition By in MS Access

Tags: t-sql, ms-access, partition

I have the following query:

```
SELECT opstudy, product_set, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY opstudy ORDER BY case_pack_qty) AS CASE_PK_RANK
FROM rngr_15_grp;
```

that I'm using in MS Access. I have the Object Designer settings set to SQL Server syntax compatible. I'm getting

> "syntax error (missing operator) in query expression `RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY opstudy ORDER BY case_pack_qty)`

What operator belongs in that expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use RANK() OVER ... in Access. The setting SQL Server Compatible Syntax (ANSI 92) implies that you must use ANSI-92 syntax for all queries. The RANK() analytic window function wasn't introduced in the ANSI standard until ANSI SQL:1999 and thus can't be used in SQL-92 mode.

Comment: @Rocketq I don't think there's anything built-in in Access to rank partitioned data this way, but it shouldn't be hard to do in VBA.